# Does $f=o(e^{x})$ yield $ \exists \rho (0<\rho<1): f=o(e^{\rho x})$?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

> Does $f=o(e^{x})$ yield  $ \exists  \rho(0<\rho<1):$ $f=o(e^{\rho x})$?

Intuitively, I think this is true since if there is no such $\rho$, it seems that $f=\Theta(e^ {x})$ which is a contradiction. I don't know how to show this.

Comment: how about $\frac{1}{x}e^x$?

Comment: @amWhy Thanks. But, are you sure I have to make this change? What is common in math literature? I thought everybody knows I am not claiming there exists 0!